# Input stream not in correct format

Tags: c#, sql

I am getting error in this line 
account = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());// ERROR
every time i am trying to run this program . Its gives me same error.The Account number is an integer and the value is coming from text box1.and the account holder name comes from text box2. this is an SQL transaction method . when i clicked the button the out put i am expecting to increase the balance or reduce the balance. this is the thing i am trying to do. I am not very expert i am trying to learn .Please replay me so i can correct this error.Thnaks

```
Here is my C# code . But when i run this application its shows following errors.Input stream not in correct format


        namespace BANKINHNTIRE1
        {
            public partial class Form3 : Form
            {
                public Form3()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

            {
                int account = System.Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
                string sql = "select statementamount from ACCOUNT WHERE Account_Number ='" + textBox1.Text + "'";

                SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=KHUNDOKARNIRJOR\KHUNDOKERNIRJOR;Initial Catalog=Login;Integrated Security=True");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
                cn.Open();
               account = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

                if (account > 0)
                {
                    int j;

                    SqlTransaction trans;
                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
                    trans = cn.BeginTransaction();
                    cmd1.Connection = cn;
                    cmd1.Transaction = trans;
                    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    cmd1.CommandText = "update ACCOUNT set statementamount=statementamount+'" + textBox3.Text + "' where Account_Number ='" + textBox1.Text + "'  and First_Name='" + textBox2.Text + "'";

                    j = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (j == 1)
                    {
                        trans.Commit();
                        MessageBox.Show("credited...");

                    }
                    else
                        trans.Rollback();


                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("u can't make credit...");
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And you're sure that the ExecuteScalar() value is what you are expecting?  Have you tried storing it in a variable and looking at it in debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *first* thing I'd check is why you trying to convert a `statementamount` (almost certainly a *floating point* value) with `int.parse()`.

You're also placing it into the variable `account` despite the fact it's *not* an account number, so it *may* be that you've mistakenly conflated `account` and `amount`, in which case it's probably better as:

```
double amount = Double.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
if (amount > 0) ...
```

In any case, you really should catch exceptions if you can recover from them, and this is certainly a case where you can do so (by, for example, putting up an error dialog then not trying to process the transaction further).

---

Beyond that, you can break down the statement into components so you can identify where the problem occurs more specifically:

```
object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
string str = obj.ToString();
account = int.Parse(str);
```

Single-stepping through that and examining the variables should hopefully make it clear what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 1):

`int.Parse` will throw an exception if the input cannot be parsed into an integer. You should only use this method if you are sure that the input looks like a number. I would guess that your select statement is returning nothing which causes the error.

You should use `int.TryParse()` instead which will return true if the parse worked. Some sample code would be

```
string input = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
int value;
bool success = int.TryParse(input, out value);

if (success)
{
    //use the value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried int.tryparse? Or have you check whether cmd.ExecuteScalar Return a null value. You haven't provide the exact error so I'm just guessing. Try this:

```
int num1 = 0;
//Check whether cm.ExecuteScalar was null, if yes then use empty string
var sqlResult = cmd.ExecuteScalar() ?? "";
//Next Try parse it to int, if it failed then return 0, you may also return null to determine that you have no records  at all.
account = int.TryParse(sqlResult .ToString(), out num1) ? num1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `int.Parse()` or you can put it under `try{} catch{}` to validate the values passed.

```
int account = 0;
try
{
    account = int.Parse(textBox1.Text.Trim());
}
 catch(Exemption emp)
{
   account=0; // or any default value
   MessageBox.Show(emp.Message);
}
```

And also, you can check it line by line by adding breakpoint on account. And debug it by pressing F11.